# OSX 10.7.5: fatal error: 'ft2build.h' file not found

Tags: macos

I am trying to install a program called "ROOT" (http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/installing-root-source) using the "make" command, but I get the following error:

```
clang++ -O2 -m64 -pipe -Wshadow -W -Wall -Woverloaded-virtual -fsigned-char -fno-common -Iinclude -pthread -I/Users/builder/pisi-64bit/tmp/freetype-2.4.4-1/install/include/freetype2 -I/Users/builder/pisi-64bit/tmp/freetype-2.4.4-1/install/include -o graf2d/graf/src/TMathText.o -c /Users/alex/root/graf2d/graf/src/TMathText.cxx
    /Users/alex/root/graf2d/graf/src/TMathText.cxx:15:12: fatal error:
    'ft2build.h' file not found
```

however, I checked and my system has the ft2build.h already:

```
    locate ft2build.h
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/X11/include/ft2build.h
    /opt/X11/include/ft2build.h
    /opt/local/include/ft2build.h
    /usr/X11/include/ft2build.h
```

How can I do so that the installation can find the ft2build.h file?

Answer (score 5):

```
brew install freetype --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/freetype
```

Comment: "Error: invalid option: --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/freetype"

Comment: 2.5 years later I found myself getting the same issue again trying to compile some libs (Tracy), yet I forgot how I fixed it. Next time I better should post the solution I find

Comment: My problem was having Conda miniforge installed which overrides `pkg-config` (see `which pkg-config` to see it its really the brew one). Solution: uninstall miniforge or adjust PATH env variable so that pkg-config is correctly resolved.

Answer (score 2):

So I recently uncovered this problem while attempting to configure PyROOT on my working version of ROOT.  If you look closely at your ./configure ... output you'll find a freestyle-config and the directory where it was found.  My problem was that this directory was the directory of my Python package which did not have the ft2build.h file plus others that are needed for ROOT.

After looking at the root-config file I saw there is an option to force make to look in the standard location which for me was /opt/local/include.  The following worked for me:

./configure macosx64 --enable-python --with-python-incdir=$PYTHONDIR/include --with-python-libdir=$PYTHONDIR/lib **--enable-builtin-freetype**

I tried using the -I technique mentioned but you will have to do that for a very large number of files (ft2build.h is the first of many files that ROOT cannot find)

You can obviously ignore the python stuff if that's not your issue but the last option is key (I bolded it for you).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to your headers to the clang include paths by using `-I` parameter:
`clang++ ... -I/opt/local/include ...` for example.

Next you'll probably get link errors - use `-L` parameter.